# Mysql how to set value for non-joined rows?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM chat JOIN users ON chat.user_id = users.id
```

Here I'am selecting the chat messages that have users, also I want to select the others chat messages that have no user(thus chat.user_id = 0) and put a value for the field "login" with value "guest" for those unjoined rows how to do that without any additional loops in the program, just in one shot mysql?

Comment: Well, add a predicate and change the `JOIN` type. I would highly encourage you to go back to SQL basics.

Comment: @Kermit fixed please review the question, it was just a typing error

Comment: For starters, this query is totally invalid.

Comment: @mariobgr fixed please review the question

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
   SELECT c.*,
          COALESCE(u.login,'guest') login
          /** other user fields **/
     FROM chat c
LEFT JOIN users u
       ON u.id = c.user_id
```

I'd still register a temporary user for guests however so that messages can be tracked to at least a session for some accountability.

If not, use `NULL` rather than `0` for no user.. that way you can still use a foreign key.